# Query to convert AWS WAF timestamp in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-waf

How to query the AWS WAF logs timestamp from Unix timestamp to normal time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime` to convert unix epoch format to timestamp format. Refer to below sample and output:

```
select from_unixtime(1594279112675/1000)

2020-07-09 07:18:32.000
```

In your case the query should be below :

```
select from_unixtime(timestamp/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this into a Datetime simply by the below syntax

```
select
    DATE(timestamp),
    ....
```